# Lambda capture by move fails for const variables

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, visual-studio-2015, c++14

I am testing Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and my compilation fails when I deal with lambda.

This is a minimal example (I know that moving a const ref does not really do a move, it is for the example):

```
#include <utility>

struct A 
{
};

void f(const A& a, const A& b)
{
    auto aa = std::move(a);                // compiles
    auto l3 = [bb = std::move(b)]() {};    // fails
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles with gcc 4.9+ and clang, but fails with msvc14 with error :

> source_file.cpp(10): error C2440: '': cannot convert from 'const A' to 'f::'
>
> source_file.cpp(10): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

I would like to understand while the move is accepted for aa and not for bb.

And if my code is correct regarding to the Standard.

Comment: I believe your code is correct according to the standard. I'm just not sure if Visual Studio 2015 is correct according to the C++14 standard on that point

Comment: Good question. FWIW, it compiles fine if you change `b` from `A const&` to `A&`, as you would need to do for this code to work sensibly anyway. I think the only real answer is to [submit a bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/) and post a link to it here.

Comment: [clang and gcc are both fine with both of those](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/257fa1f6ced2362f). Also, note you're using the copy constructor in both locations rather than the move constructor. You can't move from a const, even if it's an rvalue.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just posted https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3085991 . And of course, move ctor is not called in that case, but my real program is not exactly the same.